# Opening multiple python programs at once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to make a program in python that opens other python files at the same time. But it doesn't seem to work. The programs i am trying to run are While True loops so they run forever, so it only runs the first one while it waits for it to finish to run the next one. What can I do so they all run?

The code for my program that runs all of them is the following.

Sorry if this doesn't make much sense

```
os.system("python program1.py")
os.system("python program2.py")
os.system("python program3.py")
os.system("python program4.py")
os.system("python program5.py")
os.system("python program6.py")
os.system("python program7.py")
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you "open" other python scripts by using `import` instead of os system calls.

Comment: cos `os.system()` first one never returns! its blocking cos you have `while True` you need to use `subprocess.open()` and not this syntax.

Comment: for i in range(1,8): exec(open('python program{}.py'.format(i)))